# How to define a procedure to upgrade an add-on?

Tags: plone

When I change the profile version for an add-on that I wrote I always get the message above.

> This add-on has been upgraded. Old profile version was 10. New
>   profile version is 11. There is no upgrade procedure defined for
>   this add-on. Please consult the add-on documentation for upgrade
>   information, or contact the add-on author.

So how I can define a procedure to upgrade an add-one?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

in your configure.zcml (or preferably in a separated upgrades.zcml included in configure.zcml), you need to declare your upgrade step like that:

```
  <genericsetup:upgradeStep
  source="22"
  destination="23"
  title="Remove such js from registry"
  description=""
  profile="Products.MyProduct:default"
  handler=".upgrades.upgrade_22_to_23"
  />
```

and you need a upgrades.py file to implement the upgrade step (just an example):

```
from Products.CMFCore.utils import getToolByName

def upgrade_22_to_23(context):
    js_id = '++resource++blabla/blibli.js'
    jsregistry = getToolByName(context, 'portal_javascripts')
    jsregistry.unregisterResource(js_id)
```

Note: in zcml, source might be set to '*' if you want the step to apply from any previous profile version to the one you target.

Comment: I found in using Python `dir` that also exist the `registerResource` method. Where can I found more documentation about this topic. Is there a tutorial?

Comment: You have some documentarion here: http://developer.plone.org/components/genericsetup.html?highlight=upgradestep#id1

Comment: The registerResource method, though, comes from the Products.ResourceRegistries package, and is used for registering CSS and Javascript into the ZMI tools (portal_).

Comment: As of now, the http://developer.plone.org/components/genericsetup.html link is dead.

Comment: One minute too late ... working links: http://docs.plone.org/develop/addons/components/genericsetup.html (Plone 5), http://docs.plone.org/4/en/develop/addons/components/genericsetup.html (Plone 4)